# Find operation from GHZ state to one qubit state

Tags: quantum-phase-transition

Suppose I had some phase shifted GHZ state $\frac1{\sqrt2}(|00\cdots0\rangle+e^{i\phi}|11\cdots1\rangle)$, is there a way apply some operation such that I can get the same phase shift for some one qubit state ${\psi}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that up to global phase, you can construct the $n$-qubit state you've provided as$^1$

\begin{align}
|\phi\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |0^n\rangle + e^{i\phi}|1^n\rangle\right)\tag{1}
\\&\sim \text{CNOT}^{(n-1, n)} \text{CNOT}^{(n-2, n-1)} \cdots \text{CNOT}^{(1, 2)} R_z^{(1)}(\phi)|+\rangle|0^{n-1}\rangle\tag{2}
\end{align}
where $\text{CNOT}^{(a, b)}$ denotes a Controlled-Not controlled by qubit $a$ with qubit $b$ as the target and $a,b \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ and $R_z^{(1)}(\phi)$ is a Z-rotation by $\phi$ acting on qubit $1$, and
$$
|+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|0\rangle + |1\rangle\right) \tag{3}
$$
So assuming that you're trying to construct the state
\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|0\rangle + e^{i\phi}|1\rangle\right) \sim R_z(\phi)|+\rangle\tag{4}
\end{equation}
then you can just reverse the effect of the $\text{CNOT}$ gates in Eq. (2):

\begin{align}
|\psi\rangle|0^{n-1}\rangle = \text{CNOT}^{(1, 2)} \cdots\text{CNOT}^{(n-2, n-1)} \text{CNOT}^{(n-1, n)} |\phi\rangle \tag{5}
\end{align}

where we've used the fact that $\text{CNOT}^2 = I$, and the remaining $n-1$ qubits can be safely thrown away since they're not entangled with $|\psi\rangle$ anymore.

---

$^1$ I use "$\sim$" to denote equivalence up to global phase.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, may I ask what if $|\psi\rangle$ any random one bit state, how to transform to the assumed state?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. You're trying to transform the GHZ-like state $|\phi\rangle$ into an arbitrary single qubit state $|\psi\rangle$? If you know how to prepare $|\psi\rangle$ as $|\psi\rangle = U|0\rangle$ then you could use the same idea above, but just completely uncompute the GHZ state and then apply $U$. But it doesn't make sense why you would want to do this.

Comment: ok thanks I understand it is just different weight on $|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$, the purpose is for parallel duplicating black box operations. Also just want to assure that we can also only controlled on the first qubit instead of the consecutive bit operations?

Comment: Yes you can move all the controls to the first qubit, here I just picked the scheme that uses nearest neighbor connectivity.

Comment: sure thank you.